# How to get rid of new lines after printing from a text file, and get rid of ending space when printed

Tags: c++

```
                string foo ="";
                ifstream openfile(argv[i+1]);//argv[i+1] is file name
                if(openfile.is_open())
                { 
                    while(getline(openfile, foo))
                     {
                       istringstream myString(foo);
                       string w1;
                       while(myString >> w1)
                         cout<<w1<<' ';
                    cout <<""<< endl;
                }
```

I need to print out the text normally, meaning no extra newlines, and no space at the end of each line.

**Output**:

```
Launch Terminal
< Words Words Words                                                                                                                                                                                                       
< Words Words Words Words Words Words                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
< Words Words Words Words                                                                                                                                                                                                       
< Words Words Words Words                                                                                                                                                                                                        
< Words Words Words Words                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
< Words
```

thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is your desired output and how does that differ from the output you're getting?

Comment: Also: What exactly is your *input*?

Comment: My input is a text file that needs to be opened, read and printed out at the same time.  My desired output is basically all the lines are on top of each other. And there shouldn't be any new lines in between sentences

Comment: Why not stop at the reading of the line and print out the line? Why parse the words if you wish to exactly replicate the line? What you have will fail for input like `word1    word2 word3 word4`. The spaces between word1 and word2 will be lost and the tab between word3 and word4 will be replaced with a space. Well smurf. I can't demonstrate the error in a comment. Just imagine several spaces between word1 and word2 and a tab between word3 and word4.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to remove the new line characters, just replace them. And to get rid of the spaces at the end of each line, don't print them, you're adding them yourself xD An example code would be

```
string foo;
ifstream openfile (argv[i+1]);
if(openfile.is_open())
{ 
    while(getline(openfile, foo))
    {
        //Remove new line character, if any
        std::replace(foo.begin(), foo.end(), '\n', '');
        //Remove carraige return (windows new line is '\r\n' instead of just '\n')
        std::replace(foo.begin(), foo.end(), '\r', '');
        std::cout << foo; //print line
    }
}
```

However, maybe you actually want to add a space between each line (so after you've printed foo), as otherways the first wird of one line might stick to the last of the line before, because there's nither a space nor a line break to keep them appart)

Edit: If you want to keep the original new line characters, delete the two `std::replace(...)` lines in the code ;) You might also want to print an endl after you've printed foo, depending on what output you're expecting, as this is not very clear in your question

Edit2: As I got some more informations on what you actually want, here's an updated code that (at least) removes the additional spaces at the end of each line. If this still doesn't do what you want, be more clear about how the output of a specific file should look like!

```
string foo;
ifstream openfile (argv[i+1]);
if(openfile.is_open())
{
    while(getline(openfile, foo))
    {
        istringstream myString(foo);
        string w1;
        bool firstWord=true;
        while(myString >> w1)
        {
            if(firstWord==false)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            firstWord = false;
            cout << w1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i was trying to use sstream to break up the words to get rid of spaces. Then put them back together with only one space in between each word hence the space at the end

Comment: @JoaoSantos then, if you don't want to have a space at the end of each line, print the space BEFORE each word instead of AFTER it, and determine with a variable (for example a boolean that you set to true/false, or an int that counts the words in the current line or something like that) if you're printing the first word in this line, where you don't want to print that space. Then you'll have only one space between each word, and no space at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry I incorporated you code, and it kinda didn't do anything lol

Comment: OK well thats not going to work because Im submitting a program through an online interface that needs a specific output. If there are extra spaces it will mark the output as wrong even if its right

Comment: @JoaoSantos well, it's kinda unclear what exactly you want to achieve, so it isn't surprising that my code doesn't do what you want xD What does the file you're reading look like, and how exactly should the output for that file look like? And it will work if you do what I explained, because there won't be any extra spaces. That's why you should use a variable and determine if you're at the first word of a line, where you don't want a space to be printed.

Comment: @JoaoSantos I've edited the answer and added an code that removes the spaces at the end of each line, working as explained before.

Comment: "“Squish mode” - causes all whitespace to be squished to so that only the last whitespace character in a sequence of whitespace is printed" this is what the program is suppose to do